error when connecting google ldap with freeradius using opnsense
In this project, I try to connect Google's Ldap to Freeradius using opnsense, but there are some oddities.

When google ldap is connected to opnsense, user authentication when logging in to the web GUI is successful.
But when I try to connect google ldap to freeradius a warning appears in the freeradius log.
"ldap: WARNING: No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission to read the password attribute"

But the authentication process was successful marked with the information
" (0)Login OK: [fahrezaadi/Mypass] (from client Fazz-Radius-client port 0)
(0) Sent Access-Accept Id 3 from 192.168.66.99:1812 to 192.168.64.24:53101 length 20"`.

When I tried to connect to the radius server using the local database it was successful

Can anyone help me find the problem?
My expectation is that when Google's LDAP authentication is successful, the user can immediately connect to the radius server
I included the freeradius log and some of the configurations I did
radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####
listen {
        type = "auth"
        ipaddr = *
        port = 0
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "acct"
        ipaddr = *
        port = 0
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "auth"
        ipv6addr = ::
        port = 0
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "acct"
        ipv6addr = ::
        port = 0
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "auth"
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        port = 18120
}
Listening on auth address * port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address * port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address :: port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address :: port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel
Listening on proxy address * port 51613
Listening on proxy address :: port 34626
Ready to process requests
(0) Received Access-Request Id 3 from 192.168.64.24:53101 to 192.168.66.99:1812 length 56
(0)   User-Name = "fahrezaadi"
(0)   User-Password = "Mypassword"
(0)   Prompt = No-Echo
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     policy filter_username {
(0)       if (&User-Name) {
(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(0)       if (&User-Name)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(0)     [preprocess] = ok
(0)     [chap] = noop
(0)     [mschap] = noop
(0)     [digest] = noop
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "fahrezaadi", looking up realm NULL
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(0)     [suffix] = noop
(0) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(0)     [eap] = noop
(0)     [files] = noop
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (0)
(0) ldap: EXPAND (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%{User-Name}))
(0) ldap:    --> (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=fahrezaadi))
(0) ldap: Performing search in "dc=alazca,dc=sch,dc=id" with filter "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=fahrezaadi))", scope "sub"
(0) ldap: Waiting for search result...
(0) ldap: User object found at DN "uid=fahrezaadi,ou=Beta Tester,ou=Users,dc=alazca,dc=sch,dc=id"
(0) ldap: Processing user attributes
(0) ldap: WARNING: No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission to read the password attribute
(0) ldap: WARNING: PAP authentication will *NOT* work with Active Directory (if that is what you were trying to configure)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (0)
Need more connections to reach 10 spares
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (5), 1 of 27 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://192.168.66.99:1636
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
(0)     [ldap] = ok
(0)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password) {
(0)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  -> TRUE
(0)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  {
(0)       update control {
(0)         Auth-Type := LDAP
(0)       } # update control = noop
(0)     } # if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  = noop
(0)     [expiration] = noop
(0)     [logintime] = noop
Not doing PAP as Auth-Type is already set.
(0)     [pap] = noop
(0)   } # authorize = ok
(0) Found Auth-Type = LDAP
(0) # Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   Auth-Type LDAP {
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (1)
(0) ldap: Login attempt by "fahrezaadi"
(0) ldap: Using user DN from request "uid=fahrezaadi,ou=Beta Tester,ou=Users,dc=alazca,dc=sch,dc=id"
(0) ldap: Waiting for bind result...
(0) ldap: Bind successful
(0) ldap: Bind as user "uid=fahrezaadi,ou=Beta Tester,ou=Users,dc=alazca,dc=sch,dc=id" was successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (1)
Need more connections to reach 10 spares
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (6), 1 of 26 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://192.168.66.99:1636
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
(0)     [ldap] = ok
(0)   } # Auth-Type LDAP = ok
(0) # Executing section post-auth from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   post-auth {
(0)     update {
(0)       No attributes updated for RHS &session-state:
(0)     } # update = noop
(0)     [exec] = noop
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)   } # post-auth = noop
(0) Login OK: [fahrezaadi/Mypass] (from client Fazz-Radius-client port 0)
(0) Sent Access-Accept Id 3 from 192.168.66.99:1812 to 192.168.64.24:53101 length 20
(0) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 3 with timestamp +6 due to cleanup_delay was reached
Ready to process requests`

EAP Configuration
LDAP Configuration
NTRadping Radius Test
My expectation is that when Google's LDAP authentication is successful, the user can immediately connect to the radius server
 Radius Test Local Databas
